# How to fix "variable length differ" error in cv.zipath?

Tags: r, cross-validation

Trying to run a Cross validation of a zero-inflated poisson model using `cv.zipath` from the `mpath` package.

Fitting the LASSO

```
fit.lasso = zipath(estimation_sample_nomiss ~ .| ., 
             data = missings, 
             nlambda = 100, 
             family = "poisson", 
             link = "logit")
```

Cross validation

```
n <- dim(docvisits)[1]
K <- 10
set.seed(197)
foldid <- split(sample(1:n), rep(1:K, length = n))
fitcv <- cv.zipath(F_time_unemployed~ . | ., 
    data = estimation_sample_nomiss, family = "poisson",
                      nlambda = 100, lambda.count = fit.lasso$lambda.count[1:30],
                      lambda.zero = fit.lasso$lambda.zero[1:30], maxit.em = 300,
                      maxit.theta = 1, theta.fixed = FALSE, penalty = "enet",
                      rescale = FALSE, foldid = foldid)
```

I encounter the following error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = F_time_unemployed ~ . + ., data = list(: variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')

I have cleaned the sample of all `NA`'s but still encounter the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turns out to be that the `cv.zipath()` command does not accept tibble data formats - at least in this instance. (No guarantee as to how this statement can be generalised). Having used dplyr commands, one needs to convert back to data frame. Thus, the solution is as simple as `as.dataframe()`.